# SQL Order by Letters Ascending and Numbers Descending Same Column

Tags: mysql, sorting

I am trying to sort a column via MySQL. The sort should be ascending for letters but descending for numbers. As this might be a bit confusing here is an example:

Data to be sorted:

```
Access 2003
Access 2007
Access 2013
Aliens
Excel 2003
Excel 2007
Everybody is happy
Powerpoint 2003
Powerpoint 2007
```

Becomes

```
Access 2013
Access 2007
Access 2003
Aliens
Excel 2007
Excel 2003
Everybody is happy
Powerpoint 2007
Powerpoint 2003
```

Also just to point out the fields in question will follow the same pattern as above: The name followed by a year after a space. So if it isn't possible using a built in MYSQL function. Could we potentially split this field into 2 fields after the first space and sort by the number first then the actual field itself?

Comment: You should update your SQL table structure to store product manufacturer, product name and version separately instead of using dirty SQL hacks.

Comment: It is a course name, not a product.

Comment: Thanks for clarification but based on your question I would still recommend to split course name and year/version and leave the field empty for classes that don't need year information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to separate your field in to two fields and then order them as required.

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) AS string_name,
    TRIM( SUBSTR(fullname, LOCATE(' ', fullname)) ) AS numberpart
FROM table
```